# log4j2 causing delay in java app staring

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j2

I am using log4j2 with my java application. All is working fine in terms of the logging function however it seems to cause a very noticeable delay with starting the application.

I have strip the code to the basic

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 System.out.println("TEST");
}
```

Without including the log4j2 "TEST" appear in the console as soon as i run the app
Including the log4j2 code and folder in the build path causes a good 40-50 second delay in TEST appearing.

I am not even sure where i can start debugging this or if this is to be expected?

Note sure if this will help in term of the current setup

[image: eclipse build config]

Below is the graph of threads when starting App using VisualVM with log4j2 turn on.
[image: VisualVM Graph of threads]

Below is the graph of threads when starting App using VisualVM with /utils removed from the build path. Only thing in the /utils folder is the log4j2 .xml file
[image: threads when starting App using VisualVM with /utils removed]

log4j2.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="warn" name="app" packages="" monitorInterval="30">
<properties>
    <property name="name">app</property>
    <property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5.5p | %-10.10t | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n</property>
    <property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"</property>
</properties>
<appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
    </Console>
    <!-- File for logging general Application -->
    <RollingFile name="logGenApp" fileName="utils/AppGeneral.log" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="AppGeneral-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>"%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/> <!-- Rotated everyday -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/> <!-- OR every 1 Mb -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="92"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <!-- File for logging Database -->
    <RollingFile name="logDb" fileName="utils/Database.log" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="DB-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>"%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/> <!-- Rotated everyday -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/> <!-- OR every 1 Mb -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="92"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <!-- File for logging Gui -->
    <RollingFile name="logGui" fileName="utils/Gui.log" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="DB-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>"%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/> <!-- Rotated everyday -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/> <!-- OR every 1 Mb -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="92"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <!-- File for logging AXL -->
    <RollingFile name="logAxl" fileName="utils/AXL.log" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="DB-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>"%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/> <!-- Rotated everyday -->
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/> <!-- OR every 1 Mb -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="92"/>
    </RollingFile>
</appenders>

<!-- define all loggers -->
<loggers>
    <logger name="uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
        <appender-ref ref="logGenApp"/> <!-- And to a rotated file -->
    </logger>
    <logger name="uk.co.netpacket.utils.db" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
        <appender-ref ref="logDb"/> <!-- And to a rotated file -->
    </logger>
    <logger name="uk.co.netpacket.gui" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
        <appender-ref ref="logGui"/> <!-- And to a rotated file -->
    </logger>
    <logger name="uk.co.netpacket.utils.gui" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
        <appender-ref ref="logGui"/> <!-- And to a rotated file -->
    </logger>
    <logger name="uk.co.netpacket.utils.axl" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
        <appender-ref ref="logAxl"/> <!-- And to a rotated file -->
    </logger>
    <root level="debug"> <!-- We log only errors -->
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
    </root>
</loggers>
</configuration>
```

Flag set to Trace in log4j2.xml

```
2013-09-17 10:51:19,678 DEBUG Found Plugin Map at jar:file:/C:/Users/katsavra/Dropbox/Work/Development/Code/Java/NetQuickPhone/eclipse/NetPacket%20Quick%20Phone%20Admin/lib/log4j-core-2.0-beta8.jar!/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat
2013-09-17 10:51:21,236 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.557776437 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:22,586 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.349766816 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:23,909 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.322196820 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:25,189 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.278701201 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:26,453 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.264382587 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:27,729 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.274849980 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:29,021 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.292089766 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:30,322 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.300759774 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:31,612 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.288325335 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:32,897 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.285022848 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:34,169 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.270656640 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:35,471 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.302089055 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:36,770 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.298296067 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:38,042 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.272078870 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:39,350 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.307845169 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:40,708 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.358007914 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:42,024 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.314295601 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:43,303 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.277935213 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:44,610 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.307066303 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:45,912 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.301911556 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:47,177 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.264756622 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:48,474 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.296256790 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:49,813 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.339032335 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:51,088 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.273299525 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:52,356 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.267910166 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:53,648 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.291765565 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:54,935 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.286614179 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:56,215 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.279507505 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:57,499 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.283563102 seconds
2013-09-17 10:51:58,816 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.316436226 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:00,102 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.285968016 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:01,383 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.280116153 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:02,676 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.292500757 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:03,957 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.280316609 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:05,238 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.280846866 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:06,484 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.245982059 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:07,745 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.260707744 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:09,053 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.307244921 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:10,317 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.264032629 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:11,571 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.252440329 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:12,856 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.284874465 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:14,131 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.274280528 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:15,382 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.250523118 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:16,664 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.281563580 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:17,929 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.264700069 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:19,232 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.303086856 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:20,499 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.266067986 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:21,833 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.332428481 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:23,088 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.255274152 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:24,367 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.278314287 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:25,640 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.272656162 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:26,907 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.267301519 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:28,173 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.264851251 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:28,183 DEBUG Calling createProperty on class     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property for element property with params(name="name", value="app")
2013-09-17 10:52:28,184 DEBUG Calling createProperty on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property for element property with params(name="pattern", value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5.5p | %-10.10t | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n")
2013-09-17 10:52:28,184 DEBUG Calling createProperty on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property for element property with params(name="pattern", value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"")
2013-09-17 10:52:28,190 DEBUG Calling configureSubstitutor on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PropertiesPlugin for element properties with params(properties={name=app, pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5.5p | %-10.10t | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n, pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"}, Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:29,580 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.389516481 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:29,582 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"", Configuration(app), null, charset="null", suppressExceptions="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:31,030 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.446840212 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:31,032 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console with params(PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"), null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="Console", follow="null", suppressExceptions="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:31,033 DEBUG Jansi is not installed
2013-09-17 10:52:31,034 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern=""%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"", Configuration(app), null, charset="null", suppressExceptions="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:31,035 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(interval="null", modulate="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:31,037 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(size="1 MB")
2013-09-17 10:52:31,038 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy for element Policies with params(policies={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)})
2013-09-17 10:52:31,039 DEBUG Calling createStrategy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy for element DefaultRolloverStrategy with params(max="92", min="null", fileIndex="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:31,041 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(fileName="utils/AppGeneral.log", filePattern="AppGeneral-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log", append="null", name="logGenApp", bufferedIO="null", immediateFlush="true", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy{TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)}), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=92)), PatternLayout("%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"), null, suppressExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:31,045 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager utils/AppGeneral.log
2013-09-17 10:52:32,575 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.527935353 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:32,579 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern=""%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"", Configuration(app), null, charset="null", suppressExceptions="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:32,580 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(interval="null", modulate="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:32,581 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(size="1 MB")
2013-09-17 10:52:32,582 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy for element Policies with params(policies={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)})
2013-09-17 10:52:32,582 DEBUG Calling createStrategy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy for element DefaultRolloverStrategy with params(max="92", min="null", fileIndex="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:32,584 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(fileName="utils/Database.log", filePattern="DB-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log", append="null", name="logDb", bufferedIO="null", immediateFlush="true", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy{TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)}), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=92)), PatternLayout("%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"), null, suppressExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:32,585 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager utils/Database.log
2013-09-17 10:52:34,109 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.523256549 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:34,110 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern=""%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"", Configuration(app), null, charset="null", suppressExceptions="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:34,111 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element     TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(interval="null", modulate="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:34,111 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(size="1 MB")
2013-09-17 10:52:34,112 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy for element Policies with params(policies={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)})
2013-09-17 10:52:34,113 DEBUG Calling createStrategy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy for element DefaultRolloverStrategy with params(max="92", min="null", fileIndex="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:34,115 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(fileName="utils/Gui.log", filePattern="DB-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log", append="null", name="logGui", bufferedIO="null", immediateFlush="true", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy{TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy,     SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)}), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=92)), PatternLayout("%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"), null, suppressExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:34,116 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager utils/Gui.log
2013-09-17 10:52:35,637 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.520764846 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:35,638 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern=""%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"", Configuration(app), null, charset="null", suppressExceptions="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:35,639 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(interval="null", modulate="null")
2013-09-17 10:52:35,639 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(size="1 MB")
2013-09-17 10:52:35,640 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy for element Policies with params(policies={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)})
2013-09-17 10:52:35,640 DEBUG Calling createStrategy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy for element DefaultRolloverStrategy with params(max="92", min="null", fileIndex="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:35,642 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(fileName="utils/AXL.log", filePattern="DB-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log", append="null", name="logAxl", bufferedIO="null", immediateFlush="true", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy{TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1048576)}), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=92)), PatternLayout("%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"), null, suppressExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(app))
2013-09-17 10:52:35,644 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager utils/AXL.log
2013-09-17 10:52:37,203 DEBUG Generated plugins in 1.558124716 seconds
2013-09-17 10:52:37,204 DEBUG Calling createAppenders on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.AppendersPlugin for element appenders with params(appenders={Console, logGenApp, logDb, logGui, logAxl})
2013-09-17 10:52:37,205 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="Console", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,205 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="logGenApp", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,208 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin", includeLocation="null", appender-ref={org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@1518f00, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@18377d6}, properties={}, Configuration(app), null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,214 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="Console", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,214 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="logDb", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,216 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="uk.co.netpacket.utils.db", includeLocation="null", appender-ref={org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@5a3fa0, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@1072ac9}, properties={}, Configuration(app), null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,217 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="Console", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,218 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="logGui", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,219 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="uk.co.netpacket.gui", includeLocation="null", appender-ref={org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@18a24e9, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@7d7427}, properties={}, Configuration(app), null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,219 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="Console", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,220 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="logGui", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,221 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="uk.co.netpacket.utils.gui", includeLocation="null", appender-ref={org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@54ca71, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@b6c1e9}, properties={}, Configuration(app), null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,222 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="Console", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,222 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="logAxl", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,223 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="uk.co.netpacket.utils.axl", includeLocation="null", appender-ref={org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@74ae84, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@6d75fd}, properties={}, Configuration(app), null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,224 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element appender-ref with params(ref="Console", level="null", null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,225 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element root with params(additivity="null", level="debug", includeLocation="null", appender-ref={org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef@a487bb}, properties={}, Configuration(app), null)
2013-09-17 10:52:37,227 DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.LoggersPlugin for element loggers with params(loggers={uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin, uk.co.netpacket.utils.db, uk.co.netpacket.gui, uk.co.netpacket.utils.gui, uk.co.netpacket.utils.axl, root})
2013-09-17 10:52:37,229 DEBUG Reconfiguration completed
2013-09-17 10:52:37.347 [main] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin - Application started
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.352 [main] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin - Trying to connecto DB:utils\NetPacketQPA.sqlite
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.559 [main] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin - Connection to db successful
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.560 [main] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin - Start process to load data
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.565 [main] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.NetPacketQuickPhoneAdmin - Start to load Application data from db into objects
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.565 [main] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.utils.db.LoadData - Start to load data from CM Table
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.840 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG uk.co.netpacket.gui.Gui - IP Array[3]:30
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.842 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO  uk.co.netpacket.gui.Gui - AddTextToJTextFields called
"2013-09-17 10:52:37.842 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG uk.co.netpacket.gui.Gui - JText Field:null
"2013-09-17 10:52:43,261 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager utils/Database.log
2013-09-17 10:52:43,262 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager utils/Gui.log
2013-09-17 10:52:43,262 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager utils/AppGeneral.log
2013-09-17 10:52:43,262 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager utils/AXL.log
2013-09-17 10:52:43,262 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT
```

Thanks for the help
Alexis

Comment: There **has** to be more going on behind the scenes.  What kind of app is this - a webapp, a CLI interface?  How do you declare your use of Log4j2?

Comment: Anything to do with Log4J beta release? Do the stable releases also encounter the same issue?

Comment: @Makoto in the /utils folder is where the log4j2.xml is. This is just a Java application with a swing interface. See Edit regarding build. If i take the log4j2 out the build it app starts without delay.

Comment: @parry thanks ... didn't think of trying a different version. Will give that a go and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: @alexis Also I think you should be able to pinpoint where it spends time using something like the free VisualVM and its execution time profiler.

Comment: @parry see the edit which i included the graph produce by VisualVM ... First time i am using this toll so will take me some to time to understand the results.

Comment: RMI TCP Connector? Have You configured some HTTP Appender, which could timeout?

Comment: @alexis You can ignore all threads other than the main thread as they run async to the GUI/main thread. (If you see the other threads they continue to run past the GUI startup.) So now we need to drill down into the main thread. Take a look at this - http://rhnh.net/2011/08/03/profiling-clojure - I will open my old Swing App and try to list the steps if the above doesn't help you drill down and see which method on the main thread took up most time.

Comment: @Rekin Nope. There is AXL/SOAP request that the application sends out but nothing at startup

Comment: @parry unfortunately WebSense at work is blocking the link you sent so i will try that as soon as i get home. Having said that i dont think the issue is in the Main. If you look at the build pic above if i remove the '/utils' folder from the build path all works great (except for log4j2)! when i add it back in then i get the long delay in starting up. The '/utils' folder is where the log4j2.xml file is stored

Comment: @alexis I am a bit unclear on couple things - are you getting the delay by just importing the Log4J2 packages and adding the log4j.xml file? Or are we missing some Log4J specific code called in the main? Can you post the stripped down but complete code that recreates the issue along with the lo4j.xml you are using? (I tried a simple one here and I don't get any delay by importing, calling and tracing stuff thru log4J - so I must be missing something you are doing.)

Comment: @alexis, can you post your log4j2.xml config file? (E.g., interested to know if you're using database logging or file, etc.) Also, log4j2-beta9 is now being released and should be available for download tomorrow. You may want to try the new version as one of the bug fixes (LOG4J2-393) is related to startup time.

Comment: @parry apologies for the confusion. So this is what i have notice. In the Java Build Bath (see first pic above) if I add the **/util** folder by using the _Add Class Folder_ under _Libraries_ (eclipse then also adds the **/src** folder) Then i get this large delay at start up. Having said that apart for the delay everything works fine. If I remove the **/util** folder (eclipse then also removes the **/src** folder) the delay completely disappears at start up but log4j2 stops working. The only thing i have in **/util** is the config file for log4j2. I have added the code above.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Thanks for the interest in this. I have posted the log4j2.xml config file. I have just checked and beta8 is still the latest one but will keep an eye out for 9. Having said that i pretty confident that this is an issue i have cause and not a bug. I setup log4j2 at the start and worked fine for a long time and then this happen without and changes made to it. Could have something to do with me using **Dropbox** to synch files between my PC at work and Apple at home when working and one of the files when out of synch.. but i am just guessing now :-)

Comment: @alexis Thanks for posting the log4j2.xml; this excludes some possibilities (no custom plugins, also no JDBC appenders where DB connections could slow things down) which narrows things down. Can you try this: in the configuration element at the top of your config file, change status="warn" to status="trace". This should output log4j internal log statements which may help determine where log4j is spending time...

Comment: @RemkoPopma nice tip. Was not aware of that "trace" flag. I have added the out put. Spent a long time generating allot of plugins .. is that expected behavior?

Comment: @alexis is your log4j jar file in Dropbox folder? Looks like so from the debug output. If thats the case you might want to copy everything including the util folder to a local directory and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @parry I do run it from within my dropbox but while i am developing dropbox is switch off. In any case i did move the project to the local drive and still got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the trace output I suspect this is caused by a bug in the PluginManager (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-393). This issue is fixed in beta-9 which should be released later today. If the problem still occurs with beta-9, you may have found a new bug. In that case, could you raise a ticket in the log4j2 issue tracker?

Comment: Sounds plausible. However when I try with beta-8 I don't get any delays. Granted I've default log4j.xml but in both cases it should still generate the plugin map. May be my SSD is helping.

Comment: i have worn out the reload button at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html :-)

Comment: Beta-9 is available for download now. Sorry for the wait.

Comment: @RemkoPopma THANKS!!!!! that resolved it. I enabled the trace flag and now it only "2013-09-18 09:59:40,669 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.707043000 seconds" once. I am 99% sure it is now fix. I am working from home today on a MAC (16gb ram and ssd). Next week i be at work and want to test it on the PC there. I was sure this was an issue i caused :-) Thanks again Remko!!